# maxlength with textarea doesn't work in chrome

Tags: html

```
<textarea
  type="text"
  maxlength="300"
  />
```

maxlength is not restricting me from entering more than 300 characters in Chrome.

Comment: Try closing the `textarea` tag properly with `</textarea>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text Area maxlength not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491598/text-area-maxlength-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

The maxlength attribute is not standard for  in HTML 4.01. It is defined in HTML5. You can try to control the maxlength using javascript code. Read this answer for implementing it using javascript:https://stackoverflow.com/a/16911346/1666800